# How scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext); works in below code? And why we don't use '&' before 'var' as we do for %d or %f?

Tags: c

Code contains a structure which contains two data member `mtype` and `mtext`, `MAXSIZE` is the maximum size of that variable. I want to insert data into `mtext`.  I have the code also, but I don,t know how `scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);` here is working. And if there is any other method to do so, then please tell me.

```
struct msgbuf{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
}sbuf;

scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);
```

Comment: Answer to 2nd question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);`

1. Fails to scan anything into `sbuf.mtext` if the first character is `'\n'`.  `scanf()` returns 0.
2. Scans endless number of characters into `sbuf.mtext` until a `'\n'` is encountered and left in `stdin` and then appends a `'\0'`.  Buffer overrun possible. `scanf()` returns 1 if an overrun did not occur.  If an overrun occurs, it is undefined behavior.
3. Better to use `fgets()` to read user lines of input.

   ```
   if (fgets(sbuf.mtext, sizeof sbuf.mtext, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
   sbuf.mtext[strcspn(sbuf.mtext, "\n")] = '\0';  // drop potential \n
   ```
4. "And why we don't use '&' before 'var' as we do for %d or %f?" One question at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.